# Improve performance of the SQL query (DB2)

Tags: sql, performance, indexing, db2

I need to get the file name with records meeting a certain criteria, but I realize that the query is very slow when executing. I have added index, but it is still very slow, how can improve the performance??? I am using DB2. Please help, thank you.

**Table (FILE) (Data volume - around 100000)**

- FILE_ID
- NAME
- CATEGORY

INDEX (CATEGORY, FILE_ID)

**Table (RECORD) (Data volume - around 50000000)**

- RECORD_ID
- DATA
- CREATE_DATE
- TYPE
- FILE_ID

INDEX(CREATE_DATE, TYPE, FILE_ID)

```
SELECT NAME 
FROM FILE
WHERE CATEGORY = ? AND 
      FILE_ID IN (SELECT FILE_ID FROM RECORD WHERE CREATE_DATE = ? AND TYPE = ? )
```

Comment: IN is slower than EXISTS, try using EXISTS

Comment: Hi, I have tested some case and I found the performance of IN seems to be better than EXISTS. This is just a results I found when I check the access plan of the query. Anyway, just want to share my findings.

Answer (score 1):

Join the tables.

```
select f.name
from f join record r on f.file_id = r.file_id
where f.category = ?
```

Answer (score 1):

Try with `INNER JOIN` syntax:

```
select file.name
    from file inner join record using(file_id)
where file.category_id=? and record.create_date=? and record.type=?
```

with index(file_id, create_date, type) for record table.

Answer (score 1):

this wouldn't give you duplicate result

```
SELECT NAME 
FROM FILE F
JOIN (
    SELECT FILE_ID FROM RECORD WHERE CREATE_DATE = ? AND TYPE = ? 
    GROUP BY FILE_ID
) Q ON F.FILE_ID = Q.FILE_ID
WHERE CATEGORY = ?
```

Answer (score 1):

the join should solve your issue.

also sometimes you need to reorganize (REORG) tables and indexes to improve performance on slow queries.

Comment: Thanks, reorg does improve the performace.

Answer (score 1):

You might find that putting the "table file" into a temp table with the where clause speeds things up...

eg...

create a temp table then insert all records from Table File "Where Cateogry = ?" and then join that table onto Record